# Django:Any way to get date and name of uploaded file later?

Tags: python, django

Is there any way to get the uploaded file date and name which we have stored into the database using forms ?
Right now I am just creating two more database tuples for `name` and `date` and storing them like this 
 `file_name = request.FILES['file'].name` for file_name and storing date using `upload_date = datetime.datetime.now()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can kind of get the date after reading the metadata of the file using the `stat` module.
http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/module-stat.html

It is OS specific but `ST_CTIME` should give you approximately what you looking for.

For the name, you can easily get it from the way you store. Specify a custom handler that stores the file at `/your/file/path/filename.extension` and just manipulate the string for the filename

Just read this in the flask docs. Not sure how much it is applicable in Django but pasting here for reference

*If you want to know how the file was named on the client before it was uploaded to your application, you can access the filename attribute. However please keep in mind that this value can be forged so never ever trust that value. If you want to use the file-name of the client to store the file on the server, pass it through the secure_filename() function that Werkzeug provides for you*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the original file's name as part of the file name when storing in the disk, and you probably can use the file's creation/modification date for the upload date. IMO, you should just store it explicitly in the database.